# Binding Select Option to Model AngularJS

Tags: c#, angularjs, ng-options

After debugging it seems that the status object is getting bound to my model. But I need to bind the string to my model.

```
$scope.Statuses = [
    {name:'Not Started', value: 'Not Started'},
    {name:'In Progress', value: 'In Progress'},
    {name:'Completed', value: 'Completed'}
];

<select class="form-control" ng-model="counterMeasure.Status" ng-options="status.name for status in Statuses"></select>
```

Comment: Which string you need to bind? Then you need `select as label for value in array`

Comment: I thought it would automatically take the status.value, When I select a status in the list I want my counterMeasure.Status == status.value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use following [ngOptions](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions) syntax

> select as label for value in array

Change your code to

```
ng-options="status.value as status.name for status in Statuses"
```